# How can I do prevent downward shift of current content when the browser screen resize at responsive layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" width="300" height="300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/c80000/ffffff" width="300" height="300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" width="300" height="300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container .row {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

I use bootstrap 3 for my site and my responsive layout as below. I want to keep position of current content in viewport when browser screen resize,it not shift out of viewport.

***Current View;***

[image]

***When browser screen resize;***

[image]

***I want to it stays in the same position as like this;***

[image]

**<kbd>[Code example](http://jsbin.com/qegeraka/1/edit)</kbd>**

How can I do this?

Comment: try to specify min-width/height for image.. so that it stays even if browser resized.. like this http://jsfiddle.net/2cb5R/1/

Comment: There is no common solution how you can solve this and you would need to use js. Basicly you would need to detect the beginning of the resize and while resizing you need to fix your scrolling offset.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with an issue in switching between landscape/portrait on a specific device (e.g. iPad) then don't bother. The reality is you do not switch from a mobile phone to iPad to desktop, ever.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things proportional, use max height and/or width for the `container` div. Setting dimensions for the parent container will help A LOT with resizing issues.

Move the `HTML` image tags to before the text...

Can you post the `CSS` for `.img-responsive`?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in your custom CSS stylesheet file. This stylesheet should be placed after your bootstrap stylesheet CSS links.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-13 {
width: 50%; } }
```